# NSTimer and UIAlertController button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following simple code:

```
- (void)showAlert {
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(countdown)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];

    [UIAlertController showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"" cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" okButtonTitle:nil cancelAction:nil okAction:nil];
}

- (void)countdown {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ds", secondsLeft];
        });
        secondsLeft--;
    } else {
        [self showTimerLabel:NO];
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

So the timer starts together with alert display, but when I press the alert's button, there will be delay with the update for timerLabel text.

For example, if it's on 7s, then I press button, timerLabel will jump to 5s or 4s.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `dispatch_async` in your timer method; your timer is already running on the main queue.  `NSTimer` isn't particularly accurate.  Rather than decrementing a simple counter, I would take a `Date` when you start and then use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to get the elapsed time.  Run your timer at 0.1s rather than 1s to ensure smooth updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CADisplayLink to do this. 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-synchronize-code-to-drawing-using-cadisplaylink

Below is a code in swift 3.0 if you need i will prepare code for objective C later. Hope this will give you idea.

```
var secondsLeft = 10
var startTime: Date!
var cumulative: TimeInterval = 0.0

func timeUpdate(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    guard secondsLeft == 0 else {
        let current = Date()
        let seconds = current.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
        cumulative = cumulative + seconds
        let elapsed = Int(cumulative)
        if elapsed >= 1 {
            secondsLeft = max(0, secondsLeft - elapsed)
            if secondsLeft == 0 {
                displayLink.invalidate()
            }
            cumulative = cumulative - Double(elapsed)
        }
        startTime = current
        tickLabel.text = String(secondsLeft)
        return
    }
    displayLink.invalidate()
}

func showAlert() {
    startTime = Date()
    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(timeUpdate))
    displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive) { action in

    }
    alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```